# How to reduce header size when importing a template?

Tags: beamer, header-footer

How to reduce header size  when importing a template?  both for individual slides and in general

```
\newif\ifhandout
\input{mytalk11}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{sfasfdas}
adfsfd
 
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

`mytalk.tex` file located here https://www.dropbox.com/s/oq3jdz1devsb68o/mytalk11.tex?dl=0

The main point I'm asking is whether there is a way to override features of an input file both in general and for any particular slide